# Comparing Multivariable Boolean Functions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

An application I'm writing involved parsing plaintext into boolean lambda expressions. **For the purposes of testing**, I need to make sure this parsing is occurring correctly. To do so, I wrote a recursive expression tree comparison routine, `bool ExpressionComparison.EquvalentTo(this Expression self, Expression other)`. If `self` and `other` are both logical operators, and they share the same set of operands, `EquvalentTo` should return true.

My current algorithm uses an `ExpressionVisitor`. I pass the body of the lambda expression to this visitor and it replaces all operands (Expressions that aren't logical operators) with boolean parameters. I call this on both lambdas, compare the operands, reorder the binary parameters for the second lambda, if necessary, so the correspond to the same operands, compile the two binary functions, and exhaustively compare the results.

**Is there a more efficient way to compare the logical equivalence of two boolean functions?**

```
public static class ExpressionComparison
{
    public static bool Equals(this Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        return Compare(left, right, Equals);
    }

    public static bool EquvalentTo(this Expression self, Expression other)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(self, other))
            return true;

        if (self == null || other == null)
            return false;

        if ((self.NodeType == ExpressionType.Not || self.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso || self.NodeType == ExpressionType.OrElse) &&
            (other.NodeType == ExpressionType.Not || other.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso || other.NodeType == ExpressionType.OrElse))
            return new Visitor(self).Compare(new Visitor(other), EquvalentTo);
        else if (self.NodeType != other.NodeType)
            return false;

        if (self.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            var _self = (ConstantExpression)self;
            var _other = (ConstantExpression)other;
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(_self.Value, _other.Value))
                return true;
        }

        if (self.Type != other.Type)
            return false;

        switch (self.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Add:
            case ExpressionType.AddChecked:
            case ExpressionType.Multiply:
            case ExpressionType.MultiplyChecked:

            case ExpressionType.And:
            case ExpressionType.Or:
            case ExpressionType.ExclusiveOr:

                var selfsubs = ((BinaryExpression)self).Linearize().ToList();
                var othersubs = ((BinaryExpression)other).Linearize().ToList();

                foreach (var leftsub in selfsubs)
                {
                    int i;
                    for (i = othersubs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        if (EquvalentTo(leftsub, othersubs[i]))
                        {
                            othersubs.RemoveAt(i);
                            break;
                        }

                    if (i < 0)
                        return false;
                }

                return othersubs.Count == 0;
        }

        return Compare(self, other, EquvalentTo);
    }

    private static bool Compare(Expression self, Expression other, Func<Expression, Expression, bool> comparer)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(self, other))
            return true;

        if (self == null || other == null)
            return false;

        if (self.NodeType != other.NodeType)
            return false;

        if (self.Type != other.Type)
            return false;

        if (self is BinaryExpression)
        {
            var _left = (BinaryExpression)self;
            var _right = (BinaryExpression)other;
            return comparer(_left.Left, _right.Left) && comparer(_left.Right, _right.Right);
        }
        else if (self is ConditionalExpression)
        {
            var _left = (ConditionalExpression)self;
            var _right = (ConditionalExpression)other;
            return comparer(_left.IfFalse, _right.IfFalse) && comparer(_left.IfTrue, _right.IfTrue) && comparer(_left.Test, _right.Test);
        }
        else if (self is ConstantExpression)
        {
            var _left = (ConstantExpression)self;
            var _right = (ConstantExpression)other;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Value, _right.Value))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is DefaultExpression)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is IndexExpression)
        {
            var _left = (IndexExpression)self;
            var _right = (IndexExpression)other;
            if (_left.Arguments.Count != _right.Arguments.Count)
                return false;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Object, _right.Object))
                return false;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Indexer, _right.Indexer))
                return false;
            for (var i = _left.Arguments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!comparer(_left.Arguments[i], _right.Arguments[i]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is InvocationExpression)
        {
            var _left = (InvocationExpression)self;
            var _right = (InvocationExpression)other;
            if (_left.Arguments.Count != _right.Arguments.Count)
                return false;
            if (!comparer(_left.Expression, _right.Expression))
                return false;
            for (var i = _left.Arguments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!comparer(_left.Arguments[i], _right.Arguments[i]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is LambdaExpression)
        {
            var _left = (LambdaExpression)self;
            var _right = (LambdaExpression)other;
            if (_left.Parameters.Count != _right.Parameters.Count)
                return false;
            for (var i = _left.Parameters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!comparer(_left.Parameters[i], _right.Parameters[i]))
                    return false;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.ReturnType, _right.ReturnType))
                return false;
            return comparer(_left.Body, _right.Body);
        }
        else if (self is ListInitExpression)
        {
            var _left = (ListInitExpression)self;
            var _right = (ListInitExpression)other;
            if (comparer(_left.NewExpression, _right.NewExpression))
                return false;
            for (var i = _left.Initializers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var leftinit = _left.Initializers[i];
                var rightinit = _right.Initializers[i];
                if (Object.Equals(leftinit, rightinit))
                    continue;
                if (!Object.Equals(leftinit.AddMethod, rightinit.AddMethod))
                    return false;
                if (leftinit.Arguments.Count != rightinit.Arguments.Count)
                    return false;
                for (var j = leftinit.Arguments.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    if (!leftinit.Arguments[i].EquvalentTo(rightinit.Arguments[i]))
                        return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is MemberExpression)
        {
            var _left = (MemberExpression)self;
            var _right = (MemberExpression)other;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Member, _right.Member))
                return false;
            return comparer(_left.Expression, _right.Expression);
        }
        else if (self is MemberInitExpression)
        {

        }
        else if (self is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            var _left = (MethodCallExpression)self;
            var _right = (MethodCallExpression)other;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Method, _right.Method))
                return false;
            if (!comparer(_left.Object, _right.Object))
                return false;
            for (var i = _left.Arguments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!comparer(_left.Arguments[i], _right.Arguments[i]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is NewArrayExpression)
        {
            var _left = (NewArrayExpression)self;
            var _right = (NewArrayExpression)other;
            for (var i = _left.Expressions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!comparer(_left.Expressions[i], _right.Expressions[i]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is NewExpression)
        {
            var _left = (NewExpression)self;
            var _right = (NewExpression)other;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Constructor, _right.Constructor))
                return false;
            for (var i = _left.Members.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!Object.Equals(_left.Members[i], _right.Members[i]))
                    return false;
            for (var i = _left.Arguments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (!comparer(_left.Arguments[i], _right.Arguments[i]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is ParameterExpression)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (self is TypeBinaryExpression)
        {
            var _left = (TypeBinaryExpression)self;
            var _right = (TypeBinaryExpression)other;
            if (_left.TypeOperand != _right.TypeOperand)
                return false;
            return comparer(_left.Expression, _right.Expression);
        }
        else if (self is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var _left = (UnaryExpression)self;
            var _right = (UnaryExpression)other;
            if (!Object.Equals(_left.Method, _right.Method))
                return false;
            return comparer(_left.Operand, _right.Operand);
        }

        throw new Exception("Unhandled expression type: " + self.GetType());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Expression> Linearize(this BinaryExpression expr)
    {
        var type = expr.NodeType;

        if (expr.Left.NodeType == type)
            foreach (Expression subexpr in ((BinaryExpression)expr.Left).Linearize())
                yield return subexpr;
        else
            yield return expr.Left;

        if (expr.Right.NodeType == type)
            foreach (Expression subexpr in ((BinaryExpression)expr.Right).Linearize())
                yield return subexpr;
        else
            yield return expr.Right;
    }

    class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        IList<Expression> _expressions = new List<Expression>();
        IList<ParameterExpression> _parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();

        ParameterExpression _next(Expression expression)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Boolean));

            _expressions.Add(expression);
            _parameters.Add(parameter);

            return parameter;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Not:
                case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                    return base.Visit(node);

                default:
                    return _next(node);
            }
        }

        public Expression Visited { get; private set; }
        public Expression[] Expressions { get; private set; }
        public ParameterExpression[] Parameters { get; private set; }

        public Visitor(Expression node)
        {
            Visited = Visit(node);
            Expressions = _expressions.ToArray();
            Parameters = _parameters.ToArray();
        }

        private Delegate NaturalOrder()
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(Visited, Parameters).Compile();
        }

        private Delegate ForcedOrder(int[] order)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(Visited, order.Select(i => Parameters[i])).Compile();
        }

        public bool Compare(Visitor that, Func<Expression, Expression, bool> comparer)
        {
            if (this.Expressions.Length != that.Expressions.Length)
                return false;

            var order = new int[this.Expressions.Length];
            var CompareExpr = that.Expressions.ToArray();
            for (int i = Expressions.Length - 1, j; i >= 0; i--)
                if (comparer(Expressions[i], CompareExpr[i]))
                    order[i] = i;
                else
                {
                    for (j = CompareExpr.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                        if (i == j)
                            continue;
                        else if (comparer(Expressions[i], CompareExpr[j]))
                        {
                            order[i] = j;
                            CompareExpr[j] = null;
                            break;
                        }
                    if (j < 0)
                        return false;
                }

            dynamic thisd = this.NaturalOrder();
            dynamic thatd = that.ForcedOrder(order);
            var args = new bool[order.Length];
            for (var i = ((ulong)1 << order.Length); i > 0; i--)
            {
                for (var j = (byte)order.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    args[j] = ((i - 1) & ((ulong)1 << j)) != 0;
                if (!FuncHelper.Exec(thisd, thatd, args))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Asside/Update:** I am comparing `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>`s that I use in WHERE clauses for LINQ to Entities. I want to know that a given text string is correctly parsing into a lambda, and to do so, I compare the generated lambda against the lambda I expect. **I want to know that both lambda would return the same result set.** I can't actually test against the data, as some of the queries are intentionally absurd, to the end of making sure my parser is robust. Additionally, the data is changing, query A might be subtly different from query B, but for the moment they both return the same set, etc. So I test the lambdas for equivalence.

**I define two expressions as equivalent if one of the following:**

- `Object.Equals(a, b)` returns true
- `a` and `b` are *logically equivalent* (only applicable to `Not`, `AndAlso`, and `OrElse` nodes; defined below)
- `a` and `b` both *commutatively equivalent* (only applicable to `Add`, `Multiply`, (bitwise) `And`, `Or`, and `ExclusiveOr` nodes; defined below)
- Their `ExpressionType`s of `a` and `b` are exactly equal and all of their operands, operators, parameters, arguments, etc are Equivalent (for expressions) or Equal (for other objects).

**I define two expressions as logically equivalent if:** their 'operands' are equivalent and, if I replace each boolean operand with a boolean parameter, the two resulting n-ary boolean functions have the same truth tables. The process is as follows:

- For each, Visit the expression, skipping any nodes of NodeType `Not`, `AndAlso`, or `OrElse`, replacing other nodes with a new boolean parameter. The boolean parameters and the expressions they replace are captured in arrays.
- Check that the same number of expressions were captured.
- Compare the captured expressions of a to b, determining if they are equivalent sets, and determining the relative order (`paramA.PropA == 1 && paramB.PropB == 2` is considered equivalent to `paramB.PropB == 2 && paramA.PropA == 1`, but in more complicated cases, the different order of parameters could result in a different truth table).
- Alter the order of the boolean parameters of b so `b.Parameters[i]` corresponds to some expression `b.Expressions[j]` which is itself equivalent to `a.Expressions[i]`.
- Compile the visited expressions into two boolean functions and compare their truth tables.

**I define two expressions as commutatively equivalent if:** their `ExpressionType`s of `a` and `b` are exactly equal and if, for a and b, I walk down the tree, stopping at any `Expression` that is not the same `ExpressionType` as a/b, and put that expression in a list, the list for `a` and for `b` contain the same set of `Expressions` (determined by equivalency).

Comment: Are these binary boolean functions, n-ary, or what?  If they're binary, then why are you accepting `Expression` instances and not `Expression<Func<bool, bool, bool>>`?

Comment: What boolean operators does your expression need to support?  Only the built in C# boolean operators accepting two booleans?

Comment: The original expressions are `Expression<MyModelType, bool>`. The algorithm recursively walks the `Expression` tree, so it's not restricted to any type. If `EquvalentTo` reaches a logical operator on both sides, it hands off control to another function that builds an n-ary boolean function out of each side, assuming the non-logical operands of each side are equivalent.

Comment: It understands `Expressions` that represent `!`, `&&`, and `||`.

Comment: Include the code in your question, don't just link to it.

Comment: I forgot that SO would properly scroll it so I didn't want to bloat my post with 350 lines of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64054/discussion-between-firelizzard-and-servy).

Comment: How do you define equivalence? The same output for all inputs? You require an SAT solver for that and should expect exponential runtime.

Comment: Regarding your update: Can't you just perform an exact structural comparison and write the test lambdas to conform to the structure that your parser generates? If you don't want that: Consider using the SMT solver Z3 to test for function equivalence. Translate the lambdas into Z3 expressions. Method calls to unknown functions can be translated to uninterpreted functions.

Comment: I'd simplify the comparison logic by replacing everything that your comparer does not understand (pretty much just method calls) with a new boolean parameter. Then, you can run the truth table comparison. Shouldn't this just work? I don't see why many of matching and canonicalization steps you're doing are necessary.

Comment: @usr, That's basically what I'm doing. I'm not doing any boolean algebra cononicalization, just comparing the replaced bits. I wasn't sure if there was a non-exponential way to compare boolean functions.

Comment: No, there is not. This is the SAT problem. Note, that modern SAT solvers solve problems of thousands of variables and clauses. You can't cover such cases with combinatorial search.

Comment: @usr, Z3 worked. Don't know if it matters for my application, but it feels good to not be brute forcing it.